# Yammer REST API - Create Formatted Normal Message/Post

Tags: yammer, yammer-api

I'm trying to create posts/messages (message_type = Normal) in Yammer via the Yammer REST API (v1).  My objective is to automate the process of posting the same message to multiple groups.  The challenge I'm facing is that it appears one cannot create a "Normal" message with any kind of formatting (bold text, anchors, etc) -- while "Announcement" messages seem to allow HTML formatting.  I've tried HTML, markdown and native RTF but none of these work.  Has anyone had any success formatting (Normal) messages via the Yammer REST API?  It would also be helpful to create a post in a test group and then copy/duplicate it to other groups - but I don't see a documented/supported endpoint for that either.  Any suggestions?